Is there any way of surfacing rows read/written for each step in the Activity Runs UI?
I have a fairly simple ADF pipeline currently consisting of 5 dataflow activities.
In the Activity Runs UI I can see each of the 5 steps and access the rows read/written by clicking on the "Output" and searching through the JSON but I'd like to get these displayed in the table itself.
I've tried adding a user property of "RowsWritten" with definition @activity('MyDataflowName').output.runStatus.metrics.sink1.rowsWritten
But then I see error

ErrorCode=InvalidTemplate, ErrorMessage=cannot reference action
'MyDataflowName'. Action 'MyDataflowName'
must either be in 'runAfter' path, or be a Trigger

The best I have managed to do so far is add the user properties to the next step and then I can reference the previous activity in user properties. But this is not ideal as then the row counts are shown in the wrong step as well as needing me to add in a meaningless final activity to attach this to (as below).
Hopefully there is some way to do this that has eluded me so far?


can you add sample output?

The dataflows are all just a single source and single sink with default naming, so the output for each pipeline activity is a JSON containing paths runStatus.metrics.sink1.rowsWritten and runStatus.metrics.sink1.sources.source1.rowsRead. But I don't think the specifics are hyper relevant because an answer explaining how any value in the output can be extracted and shown in the same row as the corresponding activity in this UI would apply.

Do you want to access runStatus.metrics.sink1.rowsWritten in same activity?

@PratikLad - ideally yes. So that the values expanded from the user properties show in the row relevant to that activity, But if  I try that with syntax @activity('MyDataflowName').output.runStatus.metrics.sink1.rowsWritten it fails with error "cannot reference action 'MyDataflowName'. Action 'MyDataflowName' must either be in 'runAfter' path, or be a Trigger" - hence the workaround I am currently using of accessing it in the next activity

what is you source and sink?

Cosmos DB analytical store and Blob storage - but I'd imagine it will be the same for any?

In Azure Data Factory (ADF), there's currently no built-in feature to directly display RowsWritten or RowsRead count for each activity within the Activity Runs table using User Properties

ErrorCode=InvalidTemplate, ErrorMessage=cannot reference action 'MyDataflowName'. Action 'MyDataflowName' must either be in 'runAfter' path, or be a Trigger

The above error is causing because as you are accessing RowsWritten or RowsRead values from the output of particular activity which is not completed. Azure Data factory have activities dependencies on each other you can access the output of particular activities only after execution is completed.
The workaround for it as you provided to access the RowsWritten or RowsRead count in the User Properties of the next activity and to get the values for last activity you need to take another dummy activity so that we can fetch the rows written and read in previous activity.
The alternative way is to add set variable activity after each data flow to get the count of  RowsWritten or RowsRead from previous activity as below:


Disappointing! I already use the dummy variable activity for the last dataflow as there is no subsequent dataflow activity that I could use for this. I'm not particularly keen on adding in as many dummy activities as real activities. But potentially at least the set variable activity could be named something related to the previous step so may be more self explanatory than my current workaround. I won't mark as answered for a while in case any better solutions forthcoming
